# Can a user create another user in parse?

Tags: parse-platform

Scenario

An application built using parse that has three different types of users

USER TYPE      ROLES

user type A -  create new users from user type B and C and allocate them tasks.
User type B -  log in and complete tasks allocated by user type A. 
User type c -  Monitor tasks allocated by user type B.

User A signs up to the application then signs in to the application.
They then can create a group of users from both user type B & C , who can log in and complete individual tasks assigned to them by user type A.

My question is this possible with parse ?

Comment: You can just create a new object in the `User` class

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to set class level permission for the User class. Make sure "Allow client class creation" is set to YES. From there you can do things like create a new class called User A or B.

Creating a new class from current user would be something like:

```
- (void)newUser {
PFUser *userB = [PFUser objectWithClassName:@"UserB"];
[userB setObject:(whatever you want to add to UserB) forKey:@""];
}
```

You can even relate your new object to the user who is adding it:

```
[userB setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"creator"];
```

Here currentUser would be UserA.