# Parse: Can a user create another user?

Tags: javascript, swift, parse-platform

I have read this post: [Can a user create another user in parse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26993409/can-a-user-create-another-user-in-parse) but I don't think it answers the question.

So I will put the question this way:

I am a teacher.  I have 20 kids in my class.  I want to add them to my application because I this app allows me to enter their grades into Parse for their parents to see.  I am currently using my application to create a new user and after I successfully creating a new user, I become that user.  I don't want to become that user, I just want to create him and remain myself in the app.  How is that possible?  My app is currently using the Parse Javascript SDK.  And coming soon...it will be on iPhone using Swift.

Here is the simple code I am using:

```
var user = new Parse.User();
user.set("username", t_username.value);
user.set("password", t_password.value);
user.signUp(null, {
    success: function (user) {
        alert('New user created!');
        //but now i am that user??!?!

        },
    error: function (user, error) {
    // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to all who posted responses.  You inspired me to search for session tokens and `user.become` function.

This code does the trick!

```
var user = new Parse.User();
user.set("username", t_username.value);
user.set("password", t_password.value);

var sessionToken = Parse.User.current().get("sessionToken");
//at this point the "teacher" is the current user
//i save this user session for use later
user.signUp(null, {
    success: function (user) {
        //right now i have successfully signed up a new "student" and am actually logged in as that student
        Parse.User.become(sessionToken).then(function (user) {
        // The current user is now set back to the teacher.
        // Continue doing what you want
        }, function (error) {
            // The token could not be validated.
            alert('error');
        });
     },
        error: function (user, error) {
        // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again                    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to figure out what your User (Installation?) table is going to look like and how it is going to behave.

One solution might be to "`signUp`" your new student and whether there's a success or error, switch back to your (admin) Parse User username and password.

Another solution is to create a "Class" table in Parse in which you have a "teacher" entry and an array of "student" users (which is what the signup function could add a new student to the end of).  Then, when the student eventually logs in, their User name could be looked up across the various "student" arrays within the class table.

Comment: Teacher/Student case was an example of what I am trying to do.  There will be many "students" coming on board and going away each week and it is up to the "teacher" to manage it...no exceptions...the "students" can not sign up or manage themselves.  Right now I am using just a standard User class.

Comment: "One solution might be to "signUp" your new student and whether there's a success or error, switch back to your (admin) Parse User username and password."  Yes this is what I would like to do but don't know how...using Javascript right now.

Comment: You would get the sessionToken before creating the new user and then become: afterwards to switch back

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the other posited options is to add a cloud code function that you call and creates the user(s) for you with the supplied details.