# Possibility to create another User while logged in

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm creating a game using Parse.com as back-end. I want to create another user in Parse database while I'm still logged in. I'm using Parse `user.signUp()` method to register another user, since Parse.com provides it as a standard method for user registration. But I don't want the current user's session to expire. Currently, it works but as soon as another user is registered, the new user's session is directly logged in.

Here is the case for your information:

I want the user (e.g. myself here) to enter the email for user to invite other user to this game. When user enters email id, an email is sent actually (using PHP) and then the function creates a temporary user. For this I'm using the following code:

```
function inviteFriend() {
    var email = $("#inviteEmail").val();
    var pass = 'randomPass123';

    var varData = 'email=' + email;
    console.log(varData);

    if (email != null) {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : './src/php.php',
            data : varData,
            success : function() {
                alert("Invite sent successfully.");

                var user = new Parse.User();
                user.set("username", "tempUser");
                user.set("password", pass);
                user.set("email", email);

                user.signUp(null, {
                    success : function(user) {
                        alert("User created successfully.");
                        console.debug(user);
                    },
                    error : function(user, error) {
                        console.log("LogIn error := " + error.message);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Please suggest any workarounds.

Comment: I tried the code from this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/29442350/1169165 but it gives me error "invalid session token" with error code 209. Don't know how to proceed. Please suggest.

Comment: You can user JavaScript Local-storage which will keep data un-till you unset them ... more info is  [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: Please check the link given in first comment. That's not working as you say...